# What is a pink-comb pullet?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I have heard this phrase, used in a farming context:

> I need somebody strong enough to clear trees and heave bales, yet
>   gentle enough to yean lambs and wean pigs and tend the pink-comb
>   pullets.

What does "pink-comb pullets" mean?

I know that a pullet is a young chicken, but what does "pink-comb" mean?

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMpZ0TGjbWE

Comment: Here are some comb styles: http://www.commonweeder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/CombStyles.jpg. Source: http://www.backyardchickens.com/t/833055/50-shades-of-grey-looking-for-help-breed-and-gender/10. I think they aren't born with pink (or red) combs. *Pink* here seems to suggest that they're still young.

Comment: Thanks for the invitation! I hope someone knowing about these pullets more than me will post their answer, a definitely better answer than my guesswork. (I just found it on the web and thought it seemed like a good clue.) Let's better wait a day or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pink-comb pullet: is the young chicken, especially one that is less than one year old.

Obviously Pink-comb is the soft, red piece of flesh on the head of a male chicken.